# REST API User Resource and its Password

Tags: rest

I'm still learning REST API principles and this one still confuses me. Password inside User Resource is private and of course cannot be placed in a response, while sometimes we need to get user data for public (e.g. when someone seeing someone else's user page). How do we handle this based on REST API principles? Should I remove password inside response before sending it?

Comment: Yes, obviously you should  not return the passord in response of the user info API.

Comment: You shouldn't store the password in plain-text into the DB to start with. Note further that REST is definitely not intended to perform a 1:1 mapping from your DB model to resources. Also, business logic has hardly anything to do with REST actually, as REST just defines the common interaction pattern that should be used between clients and servers to guarantee that servers have the freedom to change in future while clients remain able to interact with the server/service further.

Comment: @RomanVottner thanks for telling that REST is not intended to perform a 1:1 mapping. It  helps me more to design my REST API.

Comment: A general tip on designing REST services is to take a closer look at how Web browsers interact with Web servers. It is therefore beneficial to first design the interaction flow between client and servers as if they were Web browser and Web server and then just use the same interaction principles such as (HTML) form resources that describe the expected input a server expects and link relation names such as next, prev, first or last to lookup the actual URI. In the browser side link relation names are often replaced by images (i.e. waste bin or pencil) to explain their affordance to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should not return the password in response. I would suggest you should create two DTOs

- UserInputDTO: This contains the password and other values
- UserOutputDTO: Here you have only those fields which are useful for the output and we can exclude password field and fields related to your internal implementation.

If your input and output looks same then you can add `JsonIgnore` annotation on the password field.

If by removing you meant setting it `null` then still the user can see the fieldname `password`, and if at any time you forgot to set it null then it will be a security issue. To solve this issue, you can use the `JsonIgnore` annotation.